# What are the inherent security vulnerabilities in the <filesystem> header?

Tags: c++, security, filesystems, c++17, google-style-guide

The [Google C++ style guide section "Other C++ features"](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Other_Features) contains the following:

> In addition to what's described in the rest of the style guide, the following C++ features may not be used:
>
> - Compile-time rational numbers (`<ratio>`), because of concerns that it's tied to a more template-heavy interface style.
> - The `<cfenv>` and `<fenv.h>` headers, because many compilers do not support those features reliably.
> - **The `<filesystem>` header, which does not have sufficient support for testing, and suffers from inherent security vulnerabilities.**

(emphasis mine)

I am aware that the Google C++ style guide can be somewhat controversial, and there are points I disagree with. Nevertheless I am curious to know what are the inherent security vulnerabilities present in the `<filesystem>` header are that this refers to, that would not be present when using some other means of accessing the file system (e.g. OS-specific API calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just that `<filesystem>` wraps system calls like `rename` rather than `renameat` and so doesn’t allow resolving a filename without being subject to [symlink attacks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink_race).  This of course doesn’t affect all use cases, but it is a legitimate concern; perhaps a future C++ version will include a descriptor-based interface.